# bootstrap modal from code-behind and browser back,forward

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, code-behind

i call bootstraps modal from code-behind,my code:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "initMyModal('" + timeRemain + "');", true);
```

in aspx page:

```
function initMyModal(timeRemain) {
    $(".modal-body").html(timeRemain);
    $('#myModal').one().modal('show');
}
```

My problem is when a user clicks on button back in browser and then click forward the modal appears again.

How can I prevent the display of the modal when users click on the forward button in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this with using cookie 
before modal is display add cookie with value when modal is showing set value in cookie